# My fragment does not fill the whole screen

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout, android-fragments, screen

I created signup and sign in the fragment but in large screens, it doesn't fill the screen, and in small screens, it slides out.

Here are the images about how it looks like in large and small screens.

My res folder directory structure.

[image]

large screen:

[image]

small screen:

[image]

Here is the xml file below :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    tools:context=".SignInFragment"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <ImageButton
            .../>

        <ImageView
            ... />

        <EditText
            ... />

        <EditText
            ... />

        <TextView
            ... />

        <Button
            .... />

        <TextView
            .../>

        <TextView
            ... />

        <View
            ... />

        <View
            ..."/>


    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: Your directory structure looks fine. Please post activity XML too  like I asked you in my first comment.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:gravity="center">

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/btn_close"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:padding="16dp"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.25" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/Sign_In_Email"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="30dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="30dp"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="Your Email"
            android:textColor="@color/cardview_light_background"
            android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
            android:textColorHint="@color/colorAccent"
            android:backgroundTint="@color/colorAccent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/Sign_In_Password"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="30dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="30dp"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="Your Password"
            android:textColor="@color/cardview_light_background"
            android:textColorHint="@color/colorAccent"
            android:backgroundTint="@color/colorAccent"
            android:inputType="textPassword"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/Sign_In_Email"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.050000012" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/Sign_In_ForgotPassword"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="33dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:text="Forgot Password?"
            android:textColor="@color/cardview_light_background"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/Sign_In_Password"
            android:layout_marginLeft="33dp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_SignIn"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="30dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="30dp"
            android:text="Sign In"
            android:textSize="15dp"
            android:textAllCaps="false"
            android:textColor="@color/cardview_light_background"
            android:background="@color/colorAccent"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/Sign_In_ForgotPassword" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="28dp"
            android:text="or"
            android:textColor="@color/cardview_light_background"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/btn_SignIn" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/dont_have_Account"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Don't have an Account? Sign Up!"
            android:textColor="@color/cardview_light_background"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.497"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView2" />

        <View
            android:id="@+id/divider"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
            android:background="@color/cardview_dark_background"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/dont_have_Account"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/textView2"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/btn_SignIn"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp" />

        <View
            android:id="@+id/divider2"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
            android:background="@color/cardview_dark_background"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/dont_have_Account"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/textView2"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/btn_SignIn"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp" />
        </LinearLayout>/


    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

You should put items in a linearlayout and set its gravity to 'center'.
This will be output in different screens:

[image]

Comment: It helped you? @mohammad pourmami

Comment: Unfortunately no !

Comment: Did you do what I said? Put items in linear layout and set its gravity to center. Linear layout should be last layer that you put items in it. Always this layer will be center of the screen. Try again my code.

Comment: See my outputs, Aren't they what you want?!